# Data interpolation of a observable in Template

Tags: angular

Code below is a part of `component.ts`

```js
export class ProfileTableComponent implements OnInit {
    
      datarender: any = [];
      datacall = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];
    
      constructor(private homepageService: HomepageService , private http: HttpClient, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataFunction();
      }
    
      dataFunction(): void {
        this.homepageService.infoData1
        .subscribe(FormData => {
        this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/supplychain/search_database' , FormData[0])
          .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
            // console.log(typeof(res));
           });
        });
      }
```

I want access the value of `res` in my component.html. How can I do that? `res` is a array of objects.

Comment: can you please access with res[0]?

Comment: How you want to do that in HTML and please also mention what you tried for better understanding about your requirements..

Answer (score 0):

You can create an observable stream and avoid an explicit `.subscribe` in your class.

```
export class Foo {
  readonly data$ = this._homepageService.infoData1
  .switchMap((FormData) => {
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:4000/supplychain/search_database' , FormData[0]);
  });
  constructor(
    private readonly _homepageService: HomepageService,
    private readonly _http: HttpClient,
  ) {
  }
}
```

Instead of `.subscribe` let Angular handle subscribing and unsubscribing from the observable inside your template via `aync` pipe.

```
<pre>{{ data$ | async }}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve this.

1. Assign the response to component property and access it in your template. Since the response is array of objects, you can display property of an object using *ngFor

   ```
    resData:Array<Object>;

        dataFunction(): void {
            this.homepageService.infoData1
            .subscribe(FormData => {
              this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/supplychain/search_database' , 
              FormData[0])
              .subscribe(res => {
                this.resData = res;
                console.log(res);
            // console.log(typeof(res));
           });
        });
      }
   ```

   //template

   ```
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let resObj of resData">
         {{resObj.prop1}},{{resObj.prop2}},{{resObj.prop3}}
        </li>
    </ul>
   ```
2. Use async pipe to render the objects through observable.

   resData$:Observable;

   ```
        dataFunction(): void {
            this.homepageService.infoData1
            .subscribe(FormData => {
              resData$ = this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/supplychain/search_database' , FormData[0])
        });
      }
   ```

   //template

   ```
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let resObj of resData$ | async">
         {{resObj.prop1}},{{resObj.prop2}},{{resObj.prop3}}
        </li>
    </ul>
   ```

Comment: Umm first method is obviously the best solution but for some reason it just isn't working.
"resData" array is showing empty.That is also the reason why I asked this question.I thought i was doing something wrong.And it would be best if i can assign POST response to a component property as it would make data manipulation far easier